# Why is Cthulhu featured in the introduction of Rick and Morty but not in any episodes?

Tags: rick-and-morty, title-sequence

In every episodes introduction Cthulhu is seen chasing them in their ship.

- Is this in any season or episode?
- If not why?

Comment: I'm not writing an answer before I didn't look up a source, but most likely the intro sequence was made early into the show, before many episodes were even produced. Because that would leave little real content to use for the sequence many scenes were probably created to represent the sorts of antics that might happen without a real episode for them to belong to.

Comment: Might be an off-topic reason here, but theories have circled about Cthulhu symbolizing Rick as being the destroyer of worlds. You can look more into that if you are interested

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**That Episode Doesn't Exist** (yet)

Before the start of Season 3 of Rick and Morty Justin Roiland was asked about Cthulhu episode being featured on Rick and Morty according to [NME](http://www.nme.com/blogs/nme-blogs/rick-and-morty-season-4-release-date-plot-and-everything-we-know-so-far-2146711)

> The trio were also asked if season 3 will feature the Cthulhu monster which was seen in the opening sequence of the show, but Roiland chose to “plead the fifth” on that. However, Ridley said that fans will be pleased as they will be seeing things that have been requested to be featured on the show.

**Why isn't Cthulhu featured in an episode?**

There's also a lot of other episodes that have featured in the intro but not featured in any episodes for example Rick and Morty getting chased by big frogs and Jerry giving birth.

These little snippets of episodes in the introduction **might be** hints at either future episodes, cancelled episodes or even deleted scenes. If an episode is cancelled/scene is deleted or that snippet isn't featured in any episodes then I guess we are just to assume that the bit in the intro happened off screen or maybe in a parallel universe etc.

Comment: "_These little snippets of episodes in the introduction are hints at either future episodes or cancelled episodes._"  I don't really agree with that line (and only really that line).  Unless you can find a source, I'm not sure if those necessarily all correspond to real plot ideas; or were thrown in exclusively for the intro.

Comment: I agree with JMac - A lot of shows will have intro-specific scenes like this. It's common enough that we can't derive a meaning without additional context.

Comment: @JMac I've tried  to get something to back me up but I couldn't find anything so I just decided to change it slightly :P

Comment: I think it's more likely these are deleted scenes rather than cancelled episodes. There isn't any evidence that any of the missing scenes were major plot points. I don't know if they release an entire season at once, but it's possible that the intro for episode 1 of a season is done before the rest of the episodes have their final edits done. I remember this happening to other TV shows but I can't sight an example.